# Como extrair todas as ocorrências de quatro dígitos após uma determinada palavra usando regex em Python?

Tags: python, regex

Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar extrair todas as ocorrências de quatro dígitos após encontrar a palavra 'Código' em uma string no Python. Atualmente, minha string se parece com isso:

```py
"Código 8781 406 407"
```

Eu tenho usado o seguinte padrão de regex para tentar alcançar esse objetivo:

```py
r'Código\s?(\d{1,4})+'
```

No entanto, este padrão só me retorna a primeira ocorrência após 'Código', que é 8781. Eu gostaria de extrair todas as ocorrências de quatro dígitos após encontrar a palavra 'Código' na string, ou seja, 8781, 406, 407

Como posso ajustar meu padrão de regex para alcançar esse resultado desejado? É importante notar que quero evitar pegar números de quatro dígitos que apareçam antes de 'Código' na minha string, pois há outros números de quatro dígitos que não são relevantes para o meu caso.

Este é meu código atual:

```py
import re

text = 'Código 8781 406 407'
padrao_codigo = r'Código\s?(\d{1,4})+'
ocorrencias = re.findall(padrao_codigo,text)
print(ocorrencias)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua regex busca por "Código", seguido de espaço, seguido de dígitos. Por isso que só encontra 8781. Os outros números não tem "Código" + espaço antes deles.

Aliás, na pergunta é dito que vc quer "extrair todas as ocorrências de quatro dígitos". Isso dá a entender que são exatamente 4 dígitos, então o 406 e 407 não deveriam estar no resultado, e a busca deveria usar `\d{4}` (exatamente 4 dígitos). Mas se a ideia é buscar "entre 1 e 4 dígitos", aí faria sentido usar `{1,4}` (vamos assumir que seja a segunda opção).

---

Se a string é **exatamente** como vc indicou, ou seja, vc já sabe que ela começa com "Código", então não precisaria verificar esta condição, bastando pegar os dígitos:

```py
import re

text = 'Código 8781 406 407'
ocorrencias = re.findall(r'\d{1,4}', text)
print(ocorrencias) # ['8781', '406', '407']
```

Você também poderia colocar um `if text.startswith('Código '):` para ter certeza que o texto começa com "Código ", por exemplo. Mas se isso já foi verificado antes e você sabe que a string sempre chega nesse formato, não seria necessário tal verificação.

E na verdade, nem precisaria de regex, bastaria quebrar a string pelo espaço e verificar se cada parte é um número entre 0 e 9999 (ou seja, entre 1 e 4 dígitos):

```py
text = 'Código 8781 406 407'
if text.startswith('Código '):
    ocorrencias = []
    for valor in text[7:].split(' '):
        try:
            if 0 <= int(valor) <= 9999: # número entre 1 e 4 dígitos
                ocorrencias.append(valor)
        except ValueError:
            # Valor não é um número válido.
            # Neste caso estou ignorando, mas poderia ter uma mensagem de erro,
            # interromper o loop, etc
            pass
    print(ocorrencias) # ['8781', '406', '407']
else:
    print("Código não encontrado")
```

Só vai dar diferença se tiver algo como "00000", pois a regex não vai pegar, mas `int` converterá para zero e irá considerar válido. Tem que ver se isso se aplica ao seu caso.

---

Agora, se a string tem mais texto, e vc só quer pegar os dígitos que vêm depois da palavra "Código", aí muda um pouco. Por exemplo, se a string fosse assim:

```
Abc blablabla 1234 5678 xyz Código 8781 406 407 blabla etc 111 333
```

Entendo que deveria pegar apenas 8781, 406 e 407. Ou o 111 e 333 também? Se for o primeiro caso, bastaria procurar números a partir de "Código", e parar quando não encontrar mais um número:

```py
import re

text = 'Abc blablabla 1234 5678 xyz Código 8781 406 407 blabla etc 111 333'
start = text.find('Código ')
if start == -1:
    print("Código não encontrado")
else:
    start += 7 # Pula a palavra "Código" e o espaço depois dela
    r = re.compile(r'\d{1,4}')
    ocorrencias = []
    while match := r.match(text, start):
        start += len(match[0]) + 1
        ocorrencias.append(match[0])
    print(ocorrencias) # ['8781', '406', '407']
```

Agora se for para pegar também o 111 e 333, bastaria um `findall` a partir da posição em que "Código" ocorre:

```py
import re

text = 'Abc blablabla 1234 5678 xyz Código 8781 406 407 blabla etc 111 333'
start = text.find('Código ')
if start == -1:
    print("Código não encontrado")
else:
    ocorrencias = re.findall(r'\d{1,4}', text[start + 7:])
    print(ocorrencias) # ['8781', '406', '407', '111', '333']
```

Enfim, qual escolher depende das variações nos dados de entrada. Uma das regras para se construir uma regex é "conheça seus dados" (se tal situação não ocorre, não vale a pena complicar à toa, mas caso ocorra, pode valer a pena para evitar falsos positivos).

E mais uma vez, neste caso também não precisa de regex, pois você pode ir percorrendo a string a partir da posição em que "Código" ocorre e verificar se cada parte é um número:

```py
text = 'Abc blablabla 1234 5678 xyz Código 8781 406 407 blabla etc 111 333'
start = text.find('Código ')
if start == -1:
    print("Código não encontrado")
else:
    ocorrencias = []
    for valor in text[start + 7:].split(' '):
        try:
            if 0 <= int(valor) <= 9999:
                ocorrencias.append(valor)
        except ValueError:
            # troque "break" por "pass" se quiser pegar também o 111 e 333
            break
    print(ocorrencias)
```

No caso, ele interrompe o for (usando `break`), assim que encontra algo que não é um número válido. Ou seja, não vai pegar 111 e 333. Mas caso queria incluí-los, troque `break` por `pass`.